# bs4 library doesn't work in pycharm but do in the cmd

Tags: python

I'm  trying to work with `beautifulsoup4` but after I install and run the following code in PyCharm:

```
import bs4
```

it doesn't work and shows the error:

`No module named 'bs4'`

Then I tried the same code in the CMD using the py command and surprisingly it works. If anyone knows what might cause the problem please help.

Answer (score 1):

be sure that the environment you installed bs4 to is also the same environment you're using in pycharm

Comment: Could you explain more